# How to convert an RDoc file to a single HTML file?

Tags: ruby, file-conversion, rdoc

I'd like to convert some RDoc files to corresponding single-page HTML files. The [rdoc](https://github.com/rdoc/rdoc) converter produces a subdirectory and multiple files, and I don't see any command-line option to change that behavior.

Is there another tool that can convert an RDoc file to a single HTML file?

Comment: In the past I used [rdoc_chm](https://rubygems.org/gems/rdoc_chm) to get a single chm file, But the gem is quiet old and I don't know if it still works wih new versions of rdoc.

Comment: @knut Thanks for the tip! This looked promising so I tried it. After some effort, I think I managed to install rdoc_chm (it required manually putting the chm generator and template under the rdoc gem directory on my system), but despite this, `rdoc --format=chm --template=chm` still generates multi-file output. It may be because I'm too unfamiliar with Ruby & rdoc to figure out what's wrong.